# How do you convert int into int64_t

Tags: ios, game-center

I am creating a game and I want to intergrate Game Center into it. I have looked and it turns out that the integer that you want to submit has to be `int64_t`. And the `int` that I am using is a standard int. how would I convert my high score `int` to an `int64_t`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to cast the `int` to `int64_t`:

```
int a = 12345;
int64_t b = (int64_t)a;
```