# Why can I not typecast from int star to void star and then to int64_t star?

Tags: c++

I have the following code, that produces junk value outputs when ran:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
void printer(void* x, int length, int y){
    if(y == 0){
        int64_t* z = (int64_t*) x;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            printf("%ld\n", z[i]);
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int length = 4;
    int* x = (int*) malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int y = 0;
    x[0] = 1;
    x[1] = 4;
    x[2] = 1;
    x[3] = 4;
    printer(x, length, y);
}

Output:
17179869185
17179869185
0
132049
```

However, when I change the type from `int` to `int64_t`in main, it works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
void printer(void* x, int length, int y){
    if(y == 0){
        int64_t* z = (int64_t*) x;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            printf("%ld\n", z[i]);
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    int length = 4;
    int64_t* x = (int64_t*) malloc(length * sizeof(int64_t));
    int y = 0;
    x[0] = 1;
    x[1] = 4;
    x[2] = 1;
    x[3] = 4;
    printer(x, length, y);
}

Output:
1
4
1
4
```

Why is this? It seems like converting between `int` and `int64_t` is fine: [How do you convert int into int64_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185782/how-do-you-convert-int-into-int64-t).
Is this due to the pointers somehow?

Comment: You're printing two `int`s from the array at once (which forms `int64t`s with high values - `17179869185 = 1 + 4 * 2^32`), the second half is out of bounds. What did you expect, and what do you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, how exactly am I printing two values at once?

Comment: `int` has at most 32 bits, `int64_t` has 64, the array elements are stored contiguously...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just casting the pointer to another type does not change the value to which the original pointer is pointing. You can only safe cast the values but not the pointers.

As you see your cast forces to read the other `int` value from index `x[1]` and displays it as `int64_t`.

Do not cast the pointer in your function - cast the value and then it works.